# Search and match an array element with struct

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

My struct:

```
typedef struct{

int parking_id;

}info;
```

In the `main()`

```
int lot_number[6]={100,101,102,103,104,105}
```

The value of the array in `lot_number`( 100, 101 to 105 )are basically the `parking_id`s, how can I match them? with pointer?

Comment: why not `info lot_number[6]={100,101,102,103,104,105}` ?

Comment: @bkVnet 
so if i do like what u said:
i can do something like this and it will link to the value on the array?
printf("Enter parking id:");
scanf("%d",&info.parking_id)

Comment: You need to specify to which element of the array to write to e.g `scanf("%d",&lot_number[0].parking_id)` write to the first element of the array.

Comment: Please define "link". Do you need to locate `info` given `parking_id`?

Comment: @bkVnet because what i'm trying to do is when prompt to enter id of parking and user select 101 it will auto refer to the array value

Comment: Are you trying to search and match an array element that has the value given by the user?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> [...] the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace-enclosed
>   list of initializers for the elements or named members.

You can simply use the initializer list, as

```
 info lot_number[6]={{100},{101},{102},{103},{104},{105}};
```

Comment: Yeah, the inner braces will make it more clear.

Comment: @bkVnet and get rid of gcc warning..due to `-Wmissing-braces`. :)

Comment: OK, i didn't use gcc often but that is a new lesson for me today. :)